# Перебирание 2 переменных str 1 циклом for

Tags: python, for

Как в цикле for можно перебрать две переменные за 1 цикл
Вот пример:

```
a = 'abcdefg'
b = '123456'
for i in a:
    for r in b:
        print(i,r)
```

Можно ли это запихнуть в 1 цикл

Comment: `for i, r in zip(a, b):` например?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Функция `zip` объединяет элементы итерируемых объектов в кортежи:

```
a = 'abcdefg'
b = '123456'
for _a, _b in zip(a, b):
    print(_a, _b)
```